# WPF Button Font Awesome

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to Add an Icon and then Aside the Button text, But when I add the fontAwesome Icon the text disapears, here my Button WPF code:

```
<Button fa:Awesome.Content="Adjust" Content="My Text" Background="#23282D" Foreground="#F1F1F1" FontSize="16" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Padding="10" BorderThickness="0"  Height="44" />
```

The Icon is here but the Text not, When I remove the Icon the text comes back again. I tried to play with Alignment and Searching here and on other Forums but can't figure out why this not work. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Should be able to just unicode inline like `content="&#xf042; My Text"`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to set the content of the button to a container (e.g. Grid or StackPanel) containing a TextBlock for the caption and an ImageAwesome control for the icon, setting the appropriate properties of each control as required.

```
<Button>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <fa:ImageAwesome Icon="Adjust" />
        <TextBlock Text="My Text" />
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much I strarted today with learning  WFP and this helped me so much!